# How make OR condition between LIKE with Datamapper?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have 3 related models:

```
class Transaction
  include DataMapper::Resource    
  property :id, Serial     
  property :volume, Float
  property :deal_date, Date  
  belongs_to :buyer
  belongs_to :seller
end

class Seller
  include DataMapper::Resource    
  property :id,         Serial
  property :name,   String      
  has n, :transactions
end

class Buyer
  include DataMapper::Resource    
  property :id, Serial
  property :name,   String, :length => 255, :index => true, :unique => true
  has n, :transactions
end
```

I want make a query to tranactions with some conditions:

```
x < volume < y
and
a < deal_date < b
and
( buyer.name like key_word OR seller.name like key_word )
```

How can I make OR condition between two LIKE with Datamapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply query `Transaction`, but with query-paths to `buyer.name` and `seller.name`.

```
Transaction.all('buyer.name.like' => keyword) | Transaction.all('seller.name.like' => keyword)
```

Comment: But it creates SQL like: `SELECT id, volume, deal_date, buyer_id, seller_id FROM transactions WHERE (id IN ? OR id IN ? ) GROUP BY id, volume, deal_date, buyer_id, seller_id ORDER BY id` and executes very slow. But i need a query with JOINs and OR between LIKE in WHERE.

Comment: Are you using MySQL by chance? MySQL does not fully support certain JOIN/sub-select optimizations, thus DataMapper has to resort to generating `WHERE (id IN (.....))`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do:

```
key_word = '%blabla%'
trs = Transaction.all condition: [
        '   buyer_id IN (SELECT id FROM buyer WHERE name LIKE ?) 
         OR seller_id IN (SELECT id FROM seller WHERE name LIKE ?)', 
      key_word, key_word]
```